# What is the difference between a Platform, a Framework, and a Package in PlatformIO?

Tags: platformio

I am working on a relatively large project and am looking to make sure I am structuring all of my code appropriately in platformIO. As I set about doing this, I have realized the documentation on the differences between the different module types in platformIO is a bit lacking. For example, they have a full page on what a Platform is but the frameworks documentation is just a list of frameworks. Some of these frameworks (notably FreeRTOS) as available for some platforms as frameworks but you could also use a normal package/library.

There may not be a "right" way to structure the project but I'd appreciate any guidance on best practices for structuring platformIO projects and the differences between these module types.

Comment: Did you ever work through this issue? I was looking at the nRF52 platform in PlatformIO to use with FreeRTOS, but it was not associated with nRF52 as one of the Frameworks.

Comment: The closest I have come to finding an answer has been this forum post over on the platformio website. https://community.platformio.org/t/frameworks-platforms-and-boards-oh-my/19178/3